# Using notion of disjoint open sets to prove a connectedness property involving separated sets

Tags: general-topology

Sets $A,B$ are separated in a space $X$ if $A \cap \overline{B}=\overline{A} \cap B=\varnothing$.

Problem:Let $A,B$ be separated subsets of a space $X$. If $C$ is a connected subset of $A \cup B$, then either $C \subset A$ or $C \subset B$.

I asked this question already. Whether I can use a certain property of separated sets to provide a solution for this question, and I was told that I couldn't. It seems to me using separated sets to answer this question over-complicates things, so I wonder if this approach is ok.

$A,B$ are open in $A \cup B$ and $C \subset A \cup B$. Thus $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ are open in $C$. If these sets are nonempty they constitute a separation of $C$ which is a contradiction. Thus $C$ is completely contained in $A$ or $B$.

On connectedness problems, when asked to use the notion of separated sets in a space to provide a solution, it seems to me most proofs involving them are more complicated than using the notion of disjoint open sets. Is it possible to always interchange to two notions in a problem like this?

Comment: You couldn’t use it **in the way that you were trying to use it**. I believe that I subsequently suggested the argument that you’re using here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sounds good I think I was just trying to make sense of the different comments thrown at me and was having trouble processing it all. I think I sort of understood that you were implying that but I couldn't fully grasp a clear image of it all.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Y = A \cup B$, where $Y$ is any space, then TFAE:

1. $A$ and $B$ are separated in $Y$.
2. $A$ and $B$ are both open and disjoint in $Y$.
3. $A$ and $B$ are both closed and disjoint in $Y$.

1 implies 3, as 1 implies $\overline{A}  \subseteq Y \setminus B \subseteq A$ and so $A$ is closed and a symmetric argument shows that $B$ is closed as well. The disjointness is then immediate from the separatedness.

3 implies 2, as $A$ and $B$ are each other's complement so $A$ closed implies $B$ open and vice versa.

2 implies 1, as $x \in \overline{A} \cap B$ would imply that $B$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and would have to intersect $B$ as $x \in \overline{B}$ too. But $A$ and $B$ are disjoint so this cannot happen. Symmetrically $\overline{B} \cap A = \emptyset$ and 1 holds.

Also, if $A$ and $B$ are separated in $X$, then $A$ and $B$ are also separated in any subspace $Y$ that contains $A$ and $B$.

So TFAE:

a. We can write $X$ as a union of two separated non-empty sets.

b. $X$ has a closed-and-open set $\emptyset \neq C \neq X$.

c. We can write $X$ as a disjoint union of two non-empty open subsets.

d. We can write $X$ as a disjoitn union of two non-empty closed subsets.

e. There is a continuous non-constant map $f: X \to \{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology.

The proofs are obvious from the first equivalence and the fact that if $X= A\cup B$, with both $A,B$ disjoint, non-empty and closed/open, then both $A$ and $B$ are non-trivial closed-and-open sets, and the observation that if we have such a partition, mapping $A$ to $0$ and $B$ to $1$ or vice versa, gives a continuous map and such a map induces a partition by $f^{-1}[\{0\}], f^{-1}[\{1\}]$. They're obvious but useful reformulations.

If $X$ satisfies one of these equivalent conditions a-e, $X$ is called *disconnected*. If $X$ is not disconnected, $X$ is called connected.

So if $A,B$ are separated in $X$, they are a disconnection of $Y=A \cup B$ and a connected subset $C$ of $Y$ must be contained in $A$ or in $B$ or else $A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ would disconnect $C$.